# Using While Loop to Keep a Databricks Job Continually Running

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-databricks

My employers are trying to continually run a Databricks notebook or a Databricks Job using a While Loop.
That is to say they intend to write a bunch of code and the encapsulate the code within a While Loop so that the entire Job/Notebook will run again after all of the code is executed.

Can someone let me know if that is a viable solution?

I should point out that they're trying to do streaming with Azure Service Bus, and because Databricks doesn't support streaming with Service Bus they're going for any solution that will keep the notebook running so as to continually read in Service Bus messages.

My personally view is that its' a terrible solution, but I'm interested to hear your comments.

Comment: This is a terrible solution. You should never use a while loop to continuously execute a program (run one then use `htop` to view the cpus if you don't believe me). The loop might also execute out of synchronization with the data i.e. how do you keep track of new/old data that needs to be processed. Figure out a way to listen to when the job needs to be executed and then do it. Maybe listen to service bus, stream that into e.g. websocket then on a message, execute Databricks notebook logic.

Comment: A Webb, thanks for your comments. I wish I could convince my employers that its a terrible solution. I explained to them that it’s complete madness. I tried to persuade them to use an alternative like Kafka, but they won’t listen to me. Therefore, I’m going to quit today, which is unfortunate as I really like the team.

Comment: Patterson, another solution is to change the Notebook to a script and run the job as a CRON, maybe every second per se. I do a lot of data infrastructure for our A.I. team and it's laughable how often I have to change their Notebooks to scripts for deployment. I hope that you do not quit but that does sound like a poor programming team. While loops always have a condition, if they were using a strong linter, it would never allow that code. Cheers

Comment: A Webb, thanks for your consideration. I honestly don't want to quit, but they're hell bent on going down the path of While Loop. I think at some point before I arrived at the organisation (6 weeks ago), they managed to prove that While Loop works during a PoC, as a result they're convinced While Loop is the way to go, and I can't persuade them otherwise. So, I will let them get on with it, but don't want no part of it. Thanks again A Webb